# What's an antonym for the adjective "concrete"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

For instance, profit margins are concrete, observable numbers whereas human needs can't easily be quantified.

The sentence I'm trying to write is:

> Due to the fact that human needs are ______, ...

Comment: ***intangible*** or ***abstract, immaterial,*** etc. If you don't like any of those, they still might be a good place to start looking for synonyms.

Comment: Intangible is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: _not quantifiable_

Answer (score 2):

@[FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) suggested in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412556/whats-an-antonym-for-the-adjective-concrete#comment984388_412556) that you could use *intangible, abstract,* or *immaterial.*

> ***intangible***: unable to be touched or grasped; not having physical presence [(Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=intangible%20define)
>
> ---
>
> ***abstract***: existing in thought or as an idea but not having a physical or concrete existence [(Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract%20define)
>
> ---
>
> ***immaterial***: not consisting of matter : INCORPOREAL [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immaterial)

Comment: I would consider using the word virtual. Or even, if the context allows—spiritual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably opt for **impalpable**, as two of the [sub/]senses overlap nicely here:

> *impalpable* [adjective]
>
> 1a: incapable of being felt by touch: intangible
>
> - *the impalpable aura of power that emanated from him* — Osbert Sitwell

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impalpable)]

> *impalpable* [adjective]:
>
> difficult to feel or [fully] understand:
>
> - *an impalpable beauty* ...

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impalpable)]

...............

While *abstract* also carries these senses, I feel its other senses exert an undesirable pull.